# How to provide screenshots to Facebook for Open Graph Action approval?

Tags: facebook

Does anybody know how to provide screenshots when you submit your action for approval? I got notification says changes needed, and they ask me for screenshots from my site where action is used. I deleted the original action because there isn't a resubmit link. But I don't find where to attach screenshots as well in the submission process. Any hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload the image file to a webserver or image hosting service and then include a links with the usage instructions when you submit your action for review.